# How to perform JAXB2 marshalling of input request in REST with Spring MVC3?

Tags: rest, spring-mvc

I am new to Spring MVC (Spring 3) and REST, and I am trying out a little toy app to try out GET and POST web services.  I have read the Spring's official reference, and found these questions in Stackoverflow, [RequestBody of a REST application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8808030/requestbody-of-a-rest-application) , [Pass a request parameter in Spring MVC 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4139538/pass-a-request-parameter-in-spring-mvc-3) but I am still stucked in making it works.  Can anyone give me hints on what I missed?

My Controller is like this:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/echo")
public class EchoControllerImpl implements EchoController {
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/echoByPost")
    public ModelAndView echoByPost(@ModelAttribute EchoDto input) {
        // ... 
    }
}
```

I have putted corresponding converter in the app ctx:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<bean id="jaxb2Marshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller" >
    <property name="classesToBeBound">
        <list>
            <value>foo.EchoDto</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <list>
            <ref bean="marshallingHttpMessageConverter" />
            <ref bean="stringHttpMessageConverter" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="stringHttpMessageConverter"
    class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter" />

<bean id="marshallingHttpMessageConverter"
    class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.MarshallingHttpMessageConverter">
    <property name="marshaller" ref="jaxb2Marshaller" />
    <property name="unmarshaller" ref="jaxb2Marshaller" />
</bean>
<!-- other beans like ViewResolvers  -->
```

I even tried to add these to web.xml as I saw somewhere mentioning about it (though I don't really know what does it means)

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>httpPutFormFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>httpPutFormFilter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>spring-rest</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
```

Then I tried to invoke my web service by Curl:
`curl -d "echoDto=<EchoDto><message>adrian</message></EchoDto>" http://localhost:8001/foo/rest/echo/echoByPost.xml`

I found that my incoming object is not created through unmarshalling of JAXB2.  Instead, seems that the ctor EchoDto(String) is called which the contains whole request xml message.

(I also tried annotating the parameter with @RequestBody instead but it is even worse, that I cannot even invoke the controller method)

Can someone tell me what I have missed?

The Jaxb2Marshaller is setup correctly with the DTO class, coz I am able to use it as returned model object in case of another GET REST webserivce call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the content type of the request and you don't need the `echoDto=`:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/xml" -d "<EchoDto><message>adrian</message></EchoDto>" http://localhost:8001/foo/rest/echo/echoByPost.xml
```

Comment: It's working.  Probably a stupid question, I want to know if my understanding is correct: "Content-Type" is affecting how the RequestMappingHfandlerAdapter deciding which message converter to use, while the .xml in the URL is affecting the how the ContentNegotiatingViewResolver deciding which view to use (base on media type).   Is my understanding correct?

Comment: That's a good question. In the example I have I don't have a `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter` defined at all, but it is still working. I wonder if Spring will use that by default if not is declared? I'll have to do a bit more digging.